# Why does lambda operator look as it does?

Tags: c#, lambda, operators, computer-science

I wonder why the lambda operator looks the way it does. The origins of the name are the [lambda calculus](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/lambda-expression) but I'm not sure why the language designers picked *=>* to denote it.

I've tried to imagine the actual lambda symbol in there but I can't see it. Is it because of some historical reference that they picked equality and inequality signs for that? Does it have any correlation with weak inequality in the other directions (the *<=* operator) that I'm missing?

I've googled it but surprisingly weirdly, nothing seems to be out there. Or I simply missed it...

If we'd get lanbd aexpression in other languages (C++, Java etc.), will the operator look the same (because of the common, to me unknown, reason)? Or can we expect the lambda operator to actually differ between languages?

Comment: This type of question is more suitable for http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: C++ has had lambda syntax for a few years now.  Looks nothing like the C# version.

Comment: @benvoigt What does it look like? According to the answer, it should be arrowy somehow in any language. Exciting to hear that lambda's been around in C++!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because it's similar to the arrow symbol used in lambda notation?

[image]

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus

subnoted in the C# wiki article about Lambda Expressions:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_Sharp_(programming_language)

Comment: I'd imagine it was easier to parse in the compiler also... irdk